# ¿Cómo capturar datos de SweetAlert2 con la tecla Intro?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Estoy trabajando con alertas, en un proyecto, para ello utilizo **sweetalert2** por sus diseños y facilidad, sin embargo me he topado con una problema. En un principio no lo creí tan importante pero ahora observo que si es tedioso en su momento.

El problema trata de lo siguiente:

**Sweetalert2** utiliza sus propias clases para `inputs` pero la desventaja es que solo se puede utilizar un `input` en las alertas, es por ello que se pueden insertar formulario de ***html*** dentro de una alerta. Sin embargo cuando utilizo un formulario ***html*** no puedo simplemente presionar la tecla ***Intro*** o ***Enter*** para enviar o realizar la acción de cargar lo que sigue de mi código.

```js
async autenticar() {
  const {
    value: formAutenticar
  } = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Autenticar Administrador',
    html: '<div class="form-inline col-sm-12 mt-3">' +
      '<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="UserName">Usuario</label>' +
      '<input required="" class="form-control col-sm-7" id="UserName" name="usuario" type="text" autofocus style="color: #2e7d32;">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-inline col-sm-12 mt-3">' +
      '<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="UserPass">Contraseña</label>' +
      '<input required="" class="form-control col-sm-7" id="UserPass" name="clave" type="password" style="color: #2e7d32;">' +
      '</div>',
    backdrop: false,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Validar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    confirmButtonColor: '#40B340',
    cancelButtonColor: '#FF0000',
    showCloseButton: true,
    focusConfirm: true,
    focusCancel: false,
    preConfirm: () => {
      return [
        document.getElementById('UserName').value,
        document.getElementById('UserPass').value
      ]
    }
  });
  if (formAutenticar && formAutenticar[0] != '' && formAutenticar[1] != '') {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Datos Correctos',
      icon: 'success',
      backdrop: false
    });
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Datos incorrectos',
      icon: 'warning',
      backdrop: false
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<button onclick="autenticar()">
      Mostrar alerta
    </button>
```

Lo que busco, como ya eh mencionado, es poder ingresar los datos y al presionar la tecla ***Intro*** poder realizar lo que sigue del código, hasta ahora lo que tengo que hacer es arrastrar el puntero y seleccionar la opcion.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podría usar la opción `onOpen` de SweetAlert2 para registrar event listeners para cada `input`que presionen el botón de confirmar cuando se presione enter ([aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp) hay un ejemplo de esto último). Esta podría ser una forma de configurar la opción `onOpen`:

```js
onOpen: (modal) => {
  confirmOnEnter = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      modal.querySelector(".swal2-confirm").click();
    }
  };
  modal.querySelector("#UserName").addEventListener("keyup", confirmOnEnter);
  modal.querySelector("#UserPass").addEventListener("keyup", confirmOnEnter);
}
```

La opción `onOpen`, según se observa en [la documentación de SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration), permite configurar una función que se ejecuta cuando se abre el modal. El elemento del DOM del modal se pasa como el primer argumento a esta función.

Este es el ejemplo completo:

```js
async function autenticar() {
  const {
    value: formAutenticar
  } = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Autenticar Administrador',
    html: '<div class="form-inline col-sm-12 mt-3">' +
      '<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="UserName">Usuario</label>' +
      '<input required="" class="form-control col-sm-7" id="UserName" name="usuario" type="text" autofocus style="color: #2e7d32;">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-inline col-sm-12 mt-3">' +
      '<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="UserPass">Contraseña</label>' +
      '<input required="" class="form-control col-sm-7" id="UserPass" name="clave" type="password" style="color: #2e7d32;">' +
      '</div>',
    backdrop: false,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Validar',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    confirmButtonColor: '#40B340',
    cancelButtonColor: '#FF0000',
    showCloseButton: true,
    focusConfirm: true,
    focusCancel: false,
    preConfirm: () => {
      return [
        document.getElementById('UserName').value,
        document.getElementById('UserPass').value
      ]
    },
    onOpen: (modal) => {
      confirmOnEnter = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          modal.querySelector(".swal2-confirm").click();
        }
      };
      modal.querySelector("#UserName").addEventListener("keyup", confirmOnEnter);
      modal.querySelector("#UserPass").addEventListener("keyup", confirmOnEnter);
    }
  });
  if (formAutenticar && formAutenticar[0] != '' && formAutenticar[1] != '') {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Datos Correctos',
      icon: 'success',
      backdrop: false
    });
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Datos incorrectos',
      icon: 'warning',
      backdrop: false
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="autenticar()">
      Mostrar alerta
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió muchísimo tu respuesta.

Comment: @AdanEscobar, me alegra. ¿Podría votar a favor o aceptarla? Ver: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)